# Does your friend get notified when you add or remove them from any list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

There are mainly 3 lists and custom options to create a new list.

**Close**, **Restricted** and **Acquaintances**

Now, if you add a friend to say Close list, will he or she get notified or is there any possibility he can find it out through some Facebook functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your friends will not be notified if you add them to lists. As per [How can I use lists to organize my friends on Facebook?](https://www.facebook.com/help/200538509990389/) article on the subject.

> "You can use lists to organize your friends on Facebook. Using a list, you can post an update for specific people, like your coworkers or friends who live near you. You can also see updates from specific groups of people (example: close friends, family).
>
> You can add or remove friends from these lists at any time. People won’t be notified when you add them to these lists."

Comment: if you know, is this up to date information on their page?

Comment: Yes it is. If they are already your friend and you are just sorting by friend group or closeness of connection they will not see any notification or other indicator that they have been placed in a category. I also included the link to the current policy page. The mod edited it to appear as Hyperlinked "Facebook Help" instead of the open URL in the response post above.

Comment: This is different from pages/people you "follow" as the pages do get notified of new followers and people may see you appear in their suggested friend recommendations if you creep their profiles.